# Get Image URL Using IMPORTXML Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm not able to get the URL link on a product page using IMPORTXML in Google Sheets.

Here is the formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://monocle.com/shop/product/1748819/issue-135/","//*[@id='content']/div/section/section[1]/div/div/div/picture/img/@src")
```

I've also tried

```
=IMPORTXML("https://monocle.com/shop/product/1748819/issue-135/","//html/body/div[1]/div/section/section[1]/div/div/div/picture/img/@src")
```

It just keeps saying:

> Error Imported content is empty.

Comment: I'm not seeing any `<picture></picture>` element in the source code of the linked page; can you clarify how you got to the conclusion that there *should* be one there?

Comment: line 1395 but I've just realised that the image url is in comments <!-- -->. Not sure how to bypass this

Comment: You may be running up against the limits of Google Sheets' support for XPath, specifically the 1.0 standard they seem to be compliant with. If their engine supported at least 3.0, you could use `parse_xml()` in your XPath to take the contents of the commented HTML and perform further drilling of the contents. You should probably look to scrape this using a more fully-fledged toolkit instead of shoehorning Sheets into doing something it's not designed to do.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get it from the `/picture/img/@src` because that element is generated dynamically. That's a limitation of importing XML.

You need to right-click on the website and then `View Source` to get the elements that are rendered.

Fortunately, there's a `script` tag where the info is displayed by using:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://monocle.com/shop/product/1748819/issue-135/","//section[@class='shop-product']//script")
```

I get as a response:

```
" var _learnq = _learnq || []; var item = { ""ProductName"": ""Issue 135"", 
""ProductID"": ""1748819"", ""SKU"": """", ""Categories"": [""print"", ""magazines""], 
""ImageURL"": 
""//img.monocle.com/product/monocle_135-5ef4abaee51e9.jpg?g=center&q=50"", 
""URL"": ""https://monocle.com/shop/product/1748819/issue-135/"", ""Brand"": """", 
""Price"": 20, ""CompareAtPrice"": 20 }; _learnq.push([""track"", ""Viewed 
Product"", item]); "
```

The Image URL is displayed. I'm thinking about a `REGEXEXTRACT` function to get the ImageURL value, but that's outside of my knowledge. But as soon as you get the ImageURL, you can use it in Sheets as

```
=IMAGE("https://img.monocle.com/product/monocle_135-5ef4abaee51e9.jpg")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and solution! It makes sense how I was not able to extract the desired image. Anyway, it worked perfectly and I made a formula to extract the image URL which is a little longer but was easy enough to make. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, for example, how about retrieving the URL from the meta tag as follows?

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@property='og:image']/@content")
```

- The URL of `https://monocle.com/shop/product/1748819/issue-135/` is put in the cell "A1".
- In this case, `https://img.monocle.com/product/monocle_135-5ef4abaee51e9.jpg?w=760&h=570` is retrieved. When you want to retrieve `https://img.monocle.com/product/monocle_135-5ef4abaee51e9.jpg`. Please use the following sample formula.

  ```
    =REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@property='og:image']/@content"),"\?.+","")
  ```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample formula is for your showing URL of `https://monocle.com/shop/product/1748819/issue-135/`. So when you changed the URL, it might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)